# Which Format is this?

Tags: python-3.x, format

Hi I know for many of you it's probably a very stupid question, but I don't have much programming experience and I'm just experimenting around with REST APIS. I came across this format which I can't assign anywhere and I can't find a formatter that puts it into a suitable format.
Can anyone do anything with the following code?

```
payload"{\"configExportP\":{\"attributes\":{\"dn\":\"uni/fabric/configexp-defaultOneTime\",\"name\":\"defaultOneTime\",\"snapshot\":\"true\",\"targetDn\":\"\",\"adminSt\":\"triggered\",\"rn\":\"configexp-defaultOneTime\",\"status\":\"created,modified\",\"descr\":\"TESTE\"},\"children\":[]}}" response: {"totalCount":"0","imdata":[]}
```

I have searched for a suitable format but found nothing

Comment: this line of code has errors all over it.  what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @D.L I'd hardly say their single line of code has "errors all over it." Based on the context of trying to use python to interface with APIs- they clearly have included a json string and are unfamiliar with the format.

Comment: Classy behavior.

Answer (score -1):

In your snippet *payload* is a json string which can be converted to a json object using json.loads(payload) which returns a dictionary. *Response* is a python dictionary.

When interfacing with APIs it is very common to both request and receive data in json format.

The 2 formats look nearly identical, but JSON is a data format while a dictionary is a python data structure. In other words, JSON is just a way to represent data in a text format.

If you copy your *payload* and paste it into http://json.parser.online.fr/ you can get an idea of how it would be structured as a JSON object. Or follow along with the excerpt below:

```
import json

# json string
payload = "{\"configExportP\":{\"attributes\":{\"dn\":\"uni/fabric/configexp-defaultOneTime\",\"name\":\"defaultOneTime\",\"snapshot\":\"true\",\"targetDn\":\"\",\"adminSt\":\"triggered\",\"rn\":\"configexp-defaultOneTime\",\"status\":\"created,modified\",\"descr\":\"TESTE\"},\"children\":[]}}"

# this is a python dictionary
response = {
    "totalCount": "0",
    "imdata": [],  # list
}

json_obj = json.loads(payload)  # json.loads() returns a python dictionary

print(json_obj['configExportP']['attributes']['dn'])  # print some value in json obj
print(response['totalCount']) # example of accessing a dictionary value by key
```

**Output:**

```
uni/fabric/configexp-defaultOneTime
0
```